# An angle between $[0, 360°[$ or $[0, 2\pi[$ is called a normalized angle. But how is called one expressed between $[-180, 180°[$ or $[-\pi, \pi[$?

Tags: angle

For a computational calculation, I need to express my resulting angles between $[-\pi, \pi[$.

I am in search of an API easing me reaching this expression, when it happens that my results are outside this interval.
But I don't know what term querying over search engines for such presentation of an angle result.

I know that an angle expressed between $[0, 360°[$ or $[0, 2\pi[$ is called a normalized angle.

But how is called an angle expressed between $[-180, 180°[$ or $[-\pi, \pi[$?
Thanks!

Comment: I'd call that normalized as well - just with a different notion of normalization.

Comment: But these notions of normalization, that are two here, don't have each one name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to name the type of normalization, I would suggest calling the one you consider standard *positive normalization* and the one you are seeking to name *balanced normalization*. Usually, authors just choose one type and stick to it throughout any given piece of work. Because of this, there is not enough usage for accepted distinguishing terms to arise.